# 13.04 sluggish after installation, live-cd was fast

Tags: 13.04, performance, macbook-air

I just installed a fresh 13.04 on my macbook, but after the installation it's a bit sluggish. Several problems occur:

- In chromium and firefox, on google.com, the autocomplete search bar lags. Sometimes it takes over 2s for the typed characters to actually appear.
- Sometimes right-click menus (for instance on the desktop) take over a second to open.
- Applications are sometimes slow to resize.
- The keyboard stalls every now and then, just a short while (probably less then a minute), but it is annoying.
- Scrolling on some webpages stalls.
- Moving windows around is slow sometimes.

None of these symptoms occur on the live-usb stick. I checked to see if I've got the right graphics drivers installed, which appears to be the case.

The machine is a MacBook Air mid 2012. I really don't know what to do next.

Edit: only weird thing I can find on the system is the fact that the installer choose to use LVM for the root partition, while there is only one disk. No idea if this is normal?

Answer (score 0):

13.04 seems to need a change of swappiness; have a look on the www. "what to do after installation of 13.04" site(s).
Alternatively the short answer is to get a Terminal, with Ctrl Alt T
 and take a look at your swappines with:-

**cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness**

if the number given is less than or equal to 30, leave it - or change to swappiness 10, with:-

**sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10**

If more problems are encountered then change swappiness back to the original number and wait for a kernel update.
I hope that that works for you!

Comment: Thanks, going to give it a try right away. For future reference I created a file /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness with the sysctl line.

Comment: I got so tired of the sluggishness that I just re-installed. After using my fresh installation for 15m it seems that it's a lot faster, I have absolutely no idea why tough. Neither am I certain that the performance will remain high, but we'll see.